# When to use setConditional method in ServerResource

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I am going through restlet documentation and came across the method [`ServerResource.setConditional(boolean`)](https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.1/jee/api/org/restlet/resource/ServerResource.html#setConditional(boolean)).

The document explains it as :

> Indicates if conditional handling is enabled. The default value is true.

Can someone please explain with a simple example when it is useful and what is the purpose of it? I have some knowledge on Jersey API but never came across such option there.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional handling in Restlet corresponds to the support of the following headers:

- `If-Match` (`request.conditions.match`)
- `If-Modified-Since` (`request.conditions.modifiedSince`)
- `If-None-Match` (request.conditions.noneMatch`)
- `If-Range` (`request.conditions.rangeTag` and `rangeDate`)
- `If-Unmodified-Since` (`request.conditions.unmodifiedSince`)

Here is a sample of use with the `If-None-Match` header:

- [Restlet client resource "not modified" condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617114/restlet-client-resource-not-modified-condition)